# Why eclipse can't run other people's java file

Tags: java, eclipse, file

[When I press run, it appears. and none of those "Ant Build" works.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHPTB.png)
If I collect one of those, it shows

*Build Failed
Reason:
Unable to find an Ant file to run.*

This file is from other. It worked well on his eclipse. Every other my files run well.

[This is from my eclips left side.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC7L2.png)

[And this is the folder that is including the files from other.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INmvh.png)

Exam3, Exam4 are from friend which have probelm right now. I have to run it and check the result. But I can't.

*When I open these files using Visul Studio Code, it works well.

*I created new file "LL" in eclipse. and it has showed in same folder with Exam3 and Exam4. So the address for the file is correct I guess.

It's been few days since I started learning Java and eclips. So it can be ridiculous question. But I really need your help. Can you help me please?

Comment: `package vari;` but folder `variable1` - ry creating a folder `vari` and moving the file to it

Comment: @user16320675 wouldn't doing the exact opposite be a whole lot easier? Change 'vari' to `variable1`, rebuild and make sure `Exam3` is your main class. It should then run

Comment: @g00se not sure, OP wrote "*This file is from other.*" so I suppose there are other computers/developers involved... It sure is an option, but I do not think that creating a folder and dragging the files into it is that much harder

Comment: Welcome! Could you please [read about why 'Can somebody help me?' is not really a question by our community's standards](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541) and [edit] to apply what you learn to ask your question? You can also see [ask] for further guidance. For example, a better question might look like: "_What is the cause of <specific issue>, and how can the problem be resolved to get <specific correct behaviour>?_"

Comment: The editor icon of `Exam3.java` is an outline `J` (instead of a regular `J` like in `Exam1.java` and `LL.java`), which means the file `Exam3.java` is not contained in a source folder, so it will not be compiled and cannot be run. Move the file `Exam3.java` into a source folder.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! I could not notice the the folder name was different. I changed the name to variable1 in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a new folder where the file name is the same  as the java public **class name** inside **src** of the new folder. You can do this by creating a new project within eclipseand file with the **same class name**.

So your file tree structure would look like **LL > src > LL.java**

And inside the java file provide the following in line 1

```
package LL;
```

Comment: if package is `LL` (not conventional name, BTW; expected all lowercase) then the direct containing folder must also be named `LL` and not `src` as indicated in this answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).